# When does Rocksmith 2014 start hiding a songs notes?

Tags: technical-issues, rocksmith-2014

Sometimes Rocksmith 2014 stops hiding the notes for the song/part you are playing, even tough you haven't failed them.

This happens usually when you restart the game, and when you come back.
Happened to me on a song I get average 99% accuracy on.

What are the exact rules by which Rocksmith 2014 starts hiding your notes for the given section or starts showing them again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rocksmith hides the notes of a song (which is called Master Mode) when you're in a section you have the full note section for and you have previously gotten a flawless playthrough on. This is easiest to see in songs that have riffs that carry out through the entire song.

Comment: And based on what does it start showing them again?

Comment: I think it's if you just start screwing it up again (which I do a lot, because I can't remember the complicated stuff) or you can turn it off in the options altogether - although that'll prevent you getting a Mastery level above 100%.

Comment: Do you have any idea what could cause it to degrade even if I don't mess up?(Not like this happens often, but its annoying)
Do you think this could be a bug?

Comment: That's not meant to happen, and it doesn't happen to me. It's possibly a bug.